# What is the difference of "concurrent" and "thread-safe" in Java 7 API documentation?

Tags: java, java-7, java.util.concurrent

I just read through the [API documentation of the java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

My impression is that "*concurrent*" and "*thread-safe*" are used synonymously there.

Example:

> ConcurrentLinkedDeque - An unbounded **concurrent** deque based on linked nodes. 
>   ConcurrentLinkedQueue - An unbounded **thread-safe** queue based on linked nodes.

*In the scope of the concurrency package* can I assume that the wording *thread-safe* and *concurrent* mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ... everything in the concurrent package can be used concurrently from different threads; e.g. thread-safe.

Specifically on the page you link to, under  the "Concurrent Collections" section:

> A concurrent collection is thread-safe, but not governed by a single exclusion lock.

Aside from that ... the entire purpose of the `java.util.concurrent.*` packages is to provide tools for concurrent (multi-threaded) programming.

See: [Oracle's Java tutorials; Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this context it means "a thread-safe collection that, being non-blocking (unlike other older collection such as Stack that use synchronization), are better suited for concurrent access".

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` documentation, and it says:

> [...] As with other concurrent collections [...]

it also says:

> [...] An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes.

Because it says that a CLQ is thread-safe, and it compares it to "other *concurrent* collections," I think we can assume that they are, in fact, used synonymously.

The only real way to find out is by inspecting the source of your Java distribution.

Comment: It seems Brian Roach posted before me, but I'll keep this here because the reasoning for our answers is different.